# Project a point on a rectangle perimeter in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, geometry, cgrect, cgpoint

I am struggling to find a simple way to get the coordinates of a CGPoint projected on a CGRect perimeter.
In other words, the point is outside a rectangle and I would like to get the intersection of the segment between the point and the center of the CGRect and the CGRect perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has some powerful methods to help with this. Check put these methods: `convertPoint:fromView:`, `convertPoint:toView:`, `convertRect:fromView:`, `convertRect:toView:`.

If I understood your question correctly this one is what you are looking for:

```
[self.view convertPoint:point fromView:subview];
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not helpful, I am not trying to convert points coordinates in one UIView to another, I just want to project this point on the perimeter of given frame.
The intersection between the vector: (point, center of the rectangle) and one of the four edges of the rectangle.